# Query for small survey to do a benchmark test

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have set up a small custom survey with this table where the answers of the users are saved:

useranswers
- id
- user_id
- question_id
- answer_option
- answer_value

Because some of the questions are multiple choice and others are not I have chosen two fields instead of one to store the chosen options (answer_option and answer_value). Only checkboxes and radio buttons are used so answer_value is always 1 or 0 and answer_option has the id of the checkbox / radio item.

Now what I'd like to do is a benchmark testing on for example question_id 1. For example I want to see a percentage of how many users have selected either 'option_a' or 'option_b'. However, I'm quite confused right now how to do that? Is it possible to do that in one query and if so how?

Because some of the users can leave during the survey I cannot count the users to have that as the total value. So I did the following to get the overall value:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `useranswers` WHERE `question_id` = '1' AND answer_option = 'option_a'
```

This gives me the total users that have participated in question_id 1. Now the question is how do I count the amount of users that have selected 'option_a' or 'option_b'.

When I use this query:

```
SELECT FROM useranswers WHERE (answer_option = 'option_a' AND answer_value = 1) OR (answer_option = 'option_b' AND answer_value = 1)
```

However, this query gives me back 4 while there are three users only. I thought it would be solved by adding a GROUP BY user_id, but that didn't work out. The output of that where three rows, which is correct, but I wanted one value back.

**Btw utdvalue is always unique so thats why I didn't use question_id in the second query**

Now the thing is that if I get the second query fixed, I am able to calculate the percentage in PHP, but that would take me two queries to do that. So I was wondering if anyone has some suggestion of how to do it better and possibly to do it in one query.

Comment: Drop everything and go learn about Third Normal Form - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form. Your database is designed incorrectly, which is why you're having trouble querying it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I read the wiki, but I don't see what's wrong with my database though. There are four tables: questions, questionoptions, users and useranswers. In the useranswers table we don't use questionoption id but the answer_option value because thats more clear for ourself and our partners. Unfortunately I can't change much of the database because I didn't design it this way :)

Comment: I'm happy to help you write a query within the confines of your data structure.  However, in your queries you reference two columns in the useranswers table: "utdvalue" and "utdchecked" that you didn't mention or explain earlier.  Could you please elaborate on what those columns represent?

Comment: Sorry, I messed that up. utdvalue should be answer_option and utdchecked should be answer_value. So answer_option is the checkbox / radio button and answer_value is 1/0, depending on whether the checbkox / radio has been selected or not. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry as a late-comer to this option... but SHOULD be relatively simple, but would be better to see some sample data to understand those that are checkbox options vs radio (multiple-choices) button.  You can use a SUM( IF() ) construct for each "condition" you want the counts from such as...

```
SELECT
      sum( if( ua.answer_option = 'option_a', 1, 0 )) as OptionACount,
      sum( if( ua.answer_option = 'option_b', 1, 0 )) as OptionBCount,
      count(*) as TotalRecordsSelected
   from
      userAnswers ua
   where
          ua.question_id = 1
      and ua.answer_value = 1
      and ua.answer_option in ( 'option_a', 'option_b' )
```

The WHERE clause is explicitly going to look only at question 1 where the answer value is 1 (assume 1 = YES or Checked), and you only care about 'option_a' or 'option_b'.

The FIELD selection does a sum() for every row.  The IF() inside the sum tests which qualifier it is counting for... option "A" or "B" respectively.  I'm sure it would get more complex with different radio buttons too, but the concept would be similar... you may just have to expand the IF() construct to include the

```
SUM( IF( answer_option = 'radio_optionX' and answer_value = 1, 1, 0 )) as RadioOpXAnswer1Count,
SUM( IF( answer_option = 'radio_optionX' and answer_value = 2, 1, 0 )) as RadioOpXAnswer2Count,
SUM( IF( answer_option = 'radio_optionX' and answer_value = 3, 1, 0 )) as RadioOpXAnswer3Count, etc...
```